# Trying to to test vimeo PHP API and getting "Unable to get an upload ticket" error

Tags: vimeo

1) Is there a sandbox I can use to test vimeo's PHP API ( github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php  ) with my basic account before going PRO? Or how do you recommend testing with "dummy" videos?

2) I received my API Key and Secret here: developer.vimeo.com/apps/[myUniqueID] .
When testing the php API, I'm able to get my user info via $user_data = $vimeo->request('/me'), but when I try to upload a file, I'm getting the following error. I tested to be sure the file is accessible with file_get_contents() and it is. Suggestions? Is this error related my account still being reviewed?

"Server reported: Unable to get an upload ticket."

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no sandbox yet for the new Vimeo API. It should be live some time in July.

You can see if your app is still pending review from your app page. If you have been approved for upload access, and you are still encountering this issue contact vimeo through https://vimeo.com/help/contact and they can find out more.

Comment: Thanks Dashron. Do you know if a sandbox is still expected to be live "some time in July"? BTW, my request for an upload ticket was denied, but they said paying for a pro account could get me one. Nice.

Comment: Certain applications types must have PRO accounts. This is covered by Vimeo's TOS, and the Vimeo API TOS.

Comment: Also, the sandbox (playground) is live! https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground.

We will be integrating it further into the dev site this week.

Comment: Hi Dashron. Don't get me wrong, I have no problem paying for a pro account ONCE I'VE SUCCESSFULLY INTEGRATED THE PHP LIBRARY INTO MY PROJECT. But how do I develop around an api that i dont even have access to? I'm simply trying to test the upload feature to handle exactly what it returns. Integrating the php api script into my project takes time. Am I expected to pay $200 for a service I won't even be using until months later once the script is finally finished? I feel like I'm missing something. Suggestions?